# schema xml sharepoint 2013 hosted app

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to update value of Major Version Limit to 50 by updating the value in schema xml in SharePoint hosted app. This do not work.

Here is my code:

```
DocLibCreation = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
DocLibCreation.set_title(DocLibName);
var DocLibTemplate = SP.ListTemplateType.documentLibrary;
DocLibCreation.set_templateType(DocLibTemplate);

DocLib = Lists.add(DocLibCreation);
context.load(DocLib, 'SchemaXml');
context.executeQueryAsync(DocumentLibraryCreationSuccess, DocumentLibraryCreationFail);

var versionLimit = DocLib.get_schemaXml();
versionLimit = versionLimit.replace('MajorVersionLimit="500"', 'MajorVersionLimit="50"');
DocLib.set_schemaXml(versionLimit);
DocLib.update(true);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Is the value just not updated or are you getting an error message?  Can you provide a sample of `versionLimit` before you try to replace the string so we can see what the XML looks like that you are trying to modify?

Comment: It's failing on DocLib.set_schemaXml(versionLimit); with object not supported